# Click event not triggered on <a> elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple `a` elements. I'm trying to handle the click event to display on alert the `id` of the clicked link but nothing is happening. Please help!

```js
$(".sites").click(function() {
  alert('handlin');
  alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="sites" id="1">test1</a>
<a href="#" class="sites" id="2">test2</a>
```

Links are generated here:

```
$.getJSON(categoriesURL, {
  term: request
}, function(data) {
  var iHtml = '';
  $.each(data, function(i, item) {
    if (10 <= i) 
      return false;
    iHtml += '<li><a href="#" class="sites" id="'+item.id+'">' + (item.title || '') + '</a></li>';
  });
  $('#categories').append(iHtml);
});
```

Comment: You code works...Have you included the `jQuey` file?

Comment: Are these links generated on the fly?

Comment: I placed your code in a snippet which works absolutely fine. If you still have issues, please check the console for errors, ensure you've included jQuery.js in the page and are running your code under a document.ready event handler.

Comment: The code you posted here works.If these links however are generated on the fly you need to use event delegation

Comment: if links generated on the fly like @ManosKounelakis said, you should $(document).on('click', '.sites', function() {   /*CODE-HERE*/   })

Comment: I guess your js is not loaded after your dom or not loaded at all, maybe you forgot jquery ?, because this is working.

Comment: @Roy I've added an edit to show how links are generated.

Comment: As the elements are dynamically generated you need to use a delegated event handler: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Could a passing dupe-hammer holder please VTC this as a dupe

Comment: may be you can use `$(document).on('click', '.sites', function() { //Your code here });`

Comment: Actually this is working `$('body').on('click', '.sites', function (e)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to bind event after ajax call done

```
 function bindButtonClick(){
       $(document).on('click', '.sites', function() {
      alert('handlin');
      alert($(this).attr("id"));
    });
    }

$.getJSON(categoriesURL, {
  term: request
}, function(data) {
  var iHtml = '';
  $.each(data, function(i, item) {
    if (10 <= i) 
      return false;
    iHtml += '<li><a href="#" class="sites" id="'+item.id+'">' + (item.title || '') + '</a></li>';
  });
  $('#categories').append(iHtml);
  bindButtonClick();
});
```

Comment: for readability, I would prefer using _live_ event listeners like 'on' as @roy commented in the original question

Comment: @PatrickFerreira updated

Comment: good, it is better than binding each time.